# Given a point $a$ in a topological space $T,$ is there a term for the set of points which are path-accessible to $a$?

Tags: general-topology

In other words: Suppose $x \in T.$ Then we can construct the set $\{y \in T : \exists f:[0,1] \rightarrow (a,b) \in T \text{ where } x,y \in \text{img}(f)\},$ or in other words: the set of points $y$ such that there exists a path $f$ in which $x$ and $y$ fall.

Comment: one has to decompose $T$ into path components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called the path-connected component (or the path-component).